# Why package depencies error is coming in Magento 1.9. please explain

Tags: magento-1.9, cli, magento-connect, package

I am working on my eCommerce website called [cravestore.in](http://cravestore.in). My magento version is **1.9.4**. I am not able to install any extensions from **Magento Connect** & **Mage** terminal both. I don't know how to fix this. I am getting package dependencies & skipping error. Also suggest how to get the extension key from Magento Marketplace. Attached are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All magento 1 extension is removed from marketplace

Comment: Y this error is coming?

Comment: because extension no longer  available! please read https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/How-Extension-Developers-Can-Prepare-for-M1-End-of-Life/ba-p/446216#:~:text=%E2%80%9CMagento%201%20will%20reach%20end,8%2F6%2F2020.%E2%80%9D

Comment: I have Magento 1.9 how to install and from where to get the extensions

Comment: you can only install them by uploading files..try to search git repo for module

Comment: Ok is there any easy way to get extensions

Comment: I think you just need to google it..

Comment: Ok I have installed one extension using ftp into Magento home directory but when I disabled from admin panel but still it shows on frontend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112788/discussion-between-pawan-and-salman-dalal).

Comment: You can try https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but what is openmage and how to use it.